# readline() tab completion automatically in uppercase and replace in place?

Tags: python, autocomplete, readline, uppercase, tab-completion

Using the library `readline` I managed to provide tab completion when using `input()`. My code until now looks like this:

```
import readline

class TabComplete:
    def __init__(self, wordList):
        self.wordList = wordList
    
    def complete(self,text,state):
        results =  [x for x in self.wordList if x.startswith(text)] + [None]
        return results[state]

readline.parse_and_bind("tab: complete")

tabComplete = ["IF", "IF_ELSE", "FOR", "WHILE"]

completer = TabComplete(tabComplete)
readline.set_completer(completer.complete)

userTyped = input("prompt > ")
```

If I start typing `I` and then hit twice on `tab` it will propose me `IF` and `IF_ELSE` as expected.
What I am searching now is:

1. if I start typing `i` and then hit twice `tab` is there a way to still make it propose `IF` and `IF_ELSE` ?
2. if I type `IF EL` can I tell him on real time to replace the space by `_` so the completion works?

Answer (score 0):

you could always convert your text to upper and replace spaces with "_"

```py
    def complete(self,text,state):
        text = tex.upper().replace(" ","_")
        results =  [x for x in self.wordList if x.startswith(text)] + [None]
        return results[state]
```